# How to use a foreach loop with a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array and I was given a foreach loop, but don't know how to echo out all the values without using print_r.  I do get a result if I `echo $array[0][0];` outside the foreach loop, for the first result.

I had seen other examples but nothing to show the results other than print_r and they tend to do only a single array, not a multidimensional array.

I had seen this foreach loop that seems like it would work, but I only get errors if I try to do `echo $new_array` inside the foreach loop.  How can I use this for something like this situation?

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
  $new_array[] = $val['key'];
}
```

array results from print_r

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [audit_inspectionID] => 10
        [1] => 2015-08-12
        [created] => 2015-08-12
        [2] => 2016-08-11 16:26:22
        [modified] => 2016-08-11 16:26:22
        [class_answer] => Array
            (
                [0] => Needs Improvement     
                [1] => Need To Correct     
                [2] => Needs Immediate Action     
            )
     )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12
        [audit_inspectionID] => 12
        [1] => 2016-08-12
        [created] => 2016-08-12
        [2] => 2016-08-11 16:26:22
        [modified] => 2016-08-11 16:26:22
        [class_answer] => Array
            (
                [0] => Needs Improvement     
                [1] => Need To Correct     
                [2] => Needs Immediate Action     
            )
     )
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of the exercise. Do you want to just echo every value in the array? Why are you doing `$new_array[]=$val['key']`

Comment: `foreach ($data as $d) foreach ($d as $k=>$v) echo $k, '->', $v, PHP_EOL;`

Comment: Also it seems like fetched from db, so you can use fetch_assoc there rather than fetch_array

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for.  Echoing each value, but can turn them into variables.

Comment: PHP_EOL when do I use this?

Comment: What if you have many multidimensional array levels is there an approach to get all the levels at once?

Comment: @Sol For that you need to write a recursive function.

Comment: @Sol You use `PHP_EOL` when you want to start a new line on a plain terminal or when writing to a file. When writing to a web page, use `<br>`.

Comment: I'm new to that kind of thinking -> recursive functions.  Could you provide me an example please.  It would call a value over and over again in itself, but not sure how to think of this in an array kind of manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but if you want something which will print out all of the keys and values (In what format? You don't specify) regardless of arrays nested inside each other you could do something like:

```
function arrayToString(array $array)
{
    $out = "";

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $out .= "$key => (" . arrayToString($value) . "), ";
        } else {
            $out .= "$key => $value, ";
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

The you can `echo arrayToString($myArray)` where `$myArray` is the array you want to echo - it'll leave trailing commas but I'm sure you can modify it to do what you need it to, this should give you an idea of how to go about it.

Is that the sort of thing you wanted? I don't really see the point of this but hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: I wanted to learn how to have more reusable code that can scale from 1 to 3 levels of multidimensional arrays.  so [] to [][][] levels.  It just seems so useful for some of the code I do.